# AngularJs pushing multiple values from array to another with databinding refreshing

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I am getting an array from the server which can contain 0..n elements in an array. I then add that to array I use locally for databinding (basically cache data in client). When doing it this way databiding works without any problems:

```
for (var i = 0 ; i < data.Result.length ; i++) {
    scope.cachedData.push(data.Result[i]);
}
```

Meaning - view refreshes, everything works. But when I try: `scope.cachedData.concat(data.Result);` it won't work. Why is that?

Comment: maybe because concat doesn't modificate the same array but return a new one... try `scope.cachedData = scope.cachedData.concat(data.Result)`

Comment: @doodeec - you are completely right. Just will this new assignment be worse than .push from performance standpoint? Is it possible to do some .pushAll() method instead of doing it in for?

Comment: I think pushing can be faster, because it doesn't change existing references in original array, it just adds a new ones... so if you are using the array in `ng-repeat`, it will update faster and element will not flash while updating

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**If you want to push everything in a single instruction use `apply` without breaking the reference to `scope.cachedData`**

```
Array.prototype.push.apply(scope.cachedData, data.Result);
```

---

Also, I know this is a little bit **off topic** but if you want to insert at a specific index you can use `splice` with `apply`

```
// I definitely want to prepend to my array here
var insertionIndex = 0,
// we don't want to delete any elements here from insertionIndex
    deleteCount = 0;
// Because we use apply the second argument is an array
// and because splice signature is (startIndex, noOfElementsToDelete, elementsToInsert)
// we need to build it
Array.prototype.splice.apply(scope.cachedData, [insertionIndex, deleteCount].concat(data.Result));
```

Imagine your array `scope.cachedData = [3,4];` and `data.Result = [1,2];`, with the code above `scope.cachedData` will become `[1,2,3,4]`.

Comment: nice one, I will definitely start to use that